# VBA: Rearranging and Exporting an Array to an Excel Worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, export

My Problem is as follows:

- Table A is sorted after numbers of type X in the first column;
    In each line several numbers of type Y may be associated with one number 
    of type X;
    Numbers of type Y may be associated with different numbers of type X
- My Goal ist to sort through the table in order to end up with a new table 
    showing all numbers of type X associated to any one number of type Y;
    (there may of course be several numbers of type X linked to one of type Y)
- I only have some Basic experience in C# and Java, None whatsoever in VBA, but 
    I whippped up some code that might do the trick if not for some error 
    messages regarding "mismatching types" of variables and incorrect indices 
    of cells.
- Basically what I wanted to do is sort through the table and see if there are 
    any entries of type Y for a number type X and if so write that X into a 
    new table into a line for the corresponding Y:

I started out rather optimistically, but there are too many unknowns regarding syntax as well as varying code samples on the net to implement sepcific steps in order for me to handle them effectively.

Could anyone give me some advice please? The idea in itself is quite simple.

Perhaps transferring the rearranged entries into another array first before writing that one back into an Excel sheet might be a better approach...

```
Sub Makro()

    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim myRow1 As Long
    Dim myRow2 As Long

    Dim myCol2 As Long

    Dim eqNo As Long

    Dim Destination As Range

    myRow1 = 1

    myRow2 = 1

    myCol2 = 2

    eqNo = 10000000
    myArr = Array(Sheets("MAT-EQ KUT").Range("C5:J1594").value)
    Sheets("Tabelle1").Activate
    Set Destination = Array(Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Resize(1801, 1590).value) = myArr
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    With Sheets("Tabelle1")

        For myRow2 = 1 To 1801
            myCol2 = 2

            Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, 1) = eqNo

            For myRow1 = 1 To 1590

                If myArr(myRow1, 2) = eqNo Then
                    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2) = myArr(myRow1, 1)

                ElseIf myArr(myRow1, 3) = eqNo Then
                    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2 + 1) = myArr(myRow1, 1)

                ElseIf myArr(myRow1, 4) = eqNo Then
                    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2 + 2) = myArr(myRow1, 1)

                ElseIf myArr(myRow1, 5) = eqNo Then
                    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2 + 3) = myArr(myRow1, 1)

                ElseIf myArr(myRow1, 6) = eqNo Then
                    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2 + 4) = myArr(myRow1, 1)

                ElseIf myArr(myRow1, 7) = eqNo Then
                    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2 + 5) = myArr(myRow1, 1)

                ElseIf myArr(myRow1, 8) = eqNo Then
                    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2 + 6) = myArr(myRow1, 1)

                End If

                myCol2 = myCol2 + 7

            Next myRow1

            eqNo = eqNo + 1

        Next myRow2

    End With

    ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Value` will already return a 2-D array if it contains multiple cells, and your nested loops assume that it has 2 dimensions.  However, when you pass a multidimensional array to `Array()`, it flattens it to one dimension:

```
myArr = Array(Sheets("MAT-EQ KUT").Range("C5:J1594").Value)
Debug.Print UBound(myArr, 1)  'Prints 10289 (8 columns * 1590 rows) 
Debug.Print UBound(myArr, 2)  'Subscript error.
```

It should be simply:

```
myArr = Sheets("MAT-EQ KUT").Range("C5:J1594").Value
```

The next issue is this line:

```
Set Destination = Array(Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Resize(1801, 1590).Value) = myArr
```

To be honest, I have no idea what this code is supposed to be doing - `Destination` is never used anywhere.  When you use `=` twice like that, what the compiler tries to do is store an object reference in `Destination`. But the right hand side of the expression is being treated as a `Boolean`. There are 2 problems with this.  First, VBA can't test for equity of two arrays like that (it throws a type mismatch) - you need to loop through the elements. Second, even if you *could*, the expression returns a `Boolean`, which can't be assigned to an object with `Set`.

I didn't get much further than that, but a couple other things to mention:

- You don't need to initialize `myRow1`, `myRow2`, or `myCol2`.  The `For myRow1 = {#} To ...` lines initialize them to whatever `#` is.
- When you create a `With` block on the line `With Sheets("Tabelle1")`, you can omit the `Sheets("Tabelle1")` everywhere inside the block.  Ie, `.Cells(myRow2, myCol2) = myArr(myRow1, 1)` instead of `Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(myRow2, myCol2) = myArr(myRow1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I thought that it would be interesting to include the test that I used to validate the code.

In the Makro all the data is loaded into and processed by arrays.  The data is then written back to the original range.

[image]

### Test

```
Sub TestMakro()
    Dim Start

    With Worksheets.Add
        .Name = "Tabelle1"
        .Range("A1") = 1
        .Range("A1").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
                                Step:=1, Stop:=1801, Trend:=False
    End With

    Start = Timer

    With Worksheets.Add
        .Name = "MAT-EQ KUT"
        .Range("C5:J1594").Formula = "=INT(RAND()*1500)"
        .Range("C5:J1594").value = .Range("C5:J1594").value
        .Range("C5:J5").value = Array(True, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    End With

    Call Makro

    Debug.Print "Time in Seconds: "; Timer - Start

End Sub
```

### Makro

```
Sub Makro()
    Dim x As Long, x1 As Long, y As Long, y1 As Long
    Dim arMAT, arTAB
    arMAT = Sheets("MAT-EQ KUT").Range("C5:J1594").value
    Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B1").Resize(1801, 1589).ClearContents
    arTAB = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Resize(1801, 1590).value

    For x = 1 To UBound(arTAB, 1)
        For x1 = 1 To UBound(arMAT, 1)
            For y1 = 2 To UBound(arMAT, 2)
                If arMAT(x1, y1) = arTAB(x, 1) Then
                    For y = 2 To UBound(arTAB, 2)
                        If IsEmpty(arTAB(x, y)) Then
                            arTAB(x, y) = arMAT(x1, 1)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

    Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Resize(1801, 1590).value = arTAB

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks many times for your quick response. I will try out your suggestions as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: The "Set Desitination" part was a snipped I took from a tutorial site in roder to define the destination to which the values should be written. BTW, the double "=" confused me, too... So, that line is basically useless.

Comment: There are times using the double equals will simplify your could eliminating an if statement.  `If A = B Then C = A` can be written `C = A = B`

Comment: Ah, ok. I made the adjustemnts you suggested and it worked. Again, many thanks.